# Why is Google Test segfaulting?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, debugging, googletest

I'm new to Google Test and I'm playing around with the provided examples. My issue is, when I introduce a failure and set `GTEST_BREAK_ON_FAILURE=1` (or use the command line option), GTest will segfault.

I am considering [this example](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample1_unittest.cc). If I insert something like this into any of the tests, I will start to get the segfault:

`EXPECT_EQ(8, 2*3);`

Just to reiterate, that is only when I have also set `GTEST_BREAK_ON_FAILURE=1`. I have run from the command line and also with gdb. If that environment variable is not set, it reports the error but does not segfault.

Any clue to what could be causing this/what I am doing wrong? I've been looking for a similar issue, but I haven't run into anything yet.

FYI I am using Google Test version 1.7.0 running on 64 bit CrunchBang Linux 11 "Waldorf".

**edit** code sample:

```
// Tests factorial of positive numbers.
TEST(FactorialTest, Positive) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, Factorial(1));
  EXPECT_EQ(2, Factorial(2));
  EXPECT_EQ(6, Factorial(3));
  EXPECT_EQ(40320, Factorial(8));
}
```

**Debugger output:**

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/yourfavoriteprotein/bin/cpp_unit_test_frameworks/gtest-1.7.0/samples/mytest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Running main() from test_main.cc
[==========] Running 6 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from FactorialTest
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Negative
[       OK ] FactorialTest.Negative (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Zero
[       OK ] FactorialTest.Zero (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Positive
sample1_unittest.cc:112: Failure
Value of: 2*3
  Actual: 6
Expected: 8

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000413427 in testing::UnitTest::AddTestPartResult(testing::TestPartResult::Type,         char const*, int, std::string const&, std::string const&) ()
(gdb) quit
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GTEST_BREAK_ON_FAILURE=1` means that Google Test [drops you into the debugger](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Turning_Assertion_Failures_into_Break-Points) if a test fails.

It so happens that an easy, portable way to drop you into the debugger is to trigger a segfault.

In other words, this behavior is by design; Google Test deliberately triggers a segfault to make the debugger run.  (See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/f570b27e15a4e921d59495622a82277a3e1e8f87/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L4154) in the Google Test code.)

Comment: Hmm, ok. Could you possibly show me the steps to get dropped into the debugger? I have tried running the test inside gdb, but it sounds like that's not the correct usage?

Comment: Running it within gdb with this option set should be correct; it should cause execution to halt at the offending line.  Then you can use normal GDB commands to investigate.  Is that not working?

Comment: no, it will segfault inside gdb, unless that's by design: (I will add the output to my question)

Comment: @yourfavoriteprotein Yes, that is by design. It's not going to "drop you to the debugger" by starting a debugger. It's Just stopping the program (by segfaulting), so if you're running the test in a debugger, you can inspect the stack trace and do basic debugging on the place it failed.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Makes sense. I'll have to mark this as answered then.